# How to send my web application request to my Facebook users

Tags: php, facebook

I want to invite my Facebook friends to my website.  So when user accept my request from facebook it will redirect  user to my site instead to opening site in Facebook iframe.

Waiting for ur response..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible - Requests will always bring the user to your canvas app - the channel exists to drive users to apps on Facebook.com. If you want to use Requests you'll need to have (at least some of) your app's functionality available through the canvas app